# Convention table names (with underscore)

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

What is the  correctly **table name** of this table in Laravel 3/4?

**Structure**
    image_projects (id, project_id, image, ext, size, created_at, updated_at, active)

```
image_projects
imageprojects
imageProjects
```

And, how I can create the Model?

```
app/models/image_projects.php
app/models/imageprojects.php
app/models/imageProjects.php
app/models/image/projects.php
app/models/projects/image.php
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It makes no difference what you name your table, as long as you then name the file & class in singular form, with the class name starting with an uppercase letter.

You can use any of the following options:

**Table name:** `image_projects`

**File name:** `ImageProject.php`

**Class name:** `ImageProject`

---

**Table name:** `imageprojects`

**File name:** `Imageproject.php`

**Class name:** `Imageproject`

---

**Table name:** `imageProjects`

**File name:** `ImageProject.php`

**Class name:** `ImageProject`

In this case you'll have to set the `$table` property yourself.

---

**Remember:** If you don't name your class in singular form of what you name your table, you'll have to manually set it in your model:

```
class ImageProjects extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'image_projects';
}
```

Comment: Also, remember that if you use underscores in your class name, you'll need to nest your models into folders (Image_project would live as /Image/project.php)

Comment: @mavrck - I don't think that you *have* to. It's an option.

Comment: @joe If you're using version 3 or 4 I believe it's required, unless you want to hack the start.php file. Because of PSR-0 rules, underscores are converted. (See here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

Comment: @JosephSilber só, the 'best pratice' is use underscore and 'nest models' into folders?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel - Yes. It seems I was wrong in assuming that folders are optional.

Comment: I can't say it is best practice to use underscores or not, I just discovered the folder nesting requirement yesterday. If I hadn't run into it myself, I wouldn't have known!

Comment: Man that blows.  I would love to know the reason for making underscored naming conventions difficult.  I just wasted 3 hours!

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew - It follows the [PSR-0 convention](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Comment: I ended up very much liking the folder convention.  Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Current Laravel version 4.2 table name convention works OK in that way:

**Table name:** `image_projects`

**File name:** `ImageProject.php`

**Class name:** `ImageProject`

The camel-case class name forced me with an exception to use table name underscores.