# Convention for table names with more than one word Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449912/convention-table-names-with-underscore) which was for laravel 3.

I have a table name `active_permits`

What should be filename and class name?

Answer (score 9):

File: ActivePermit.php
Class: ActivePermit