# Many to many relationship in laravel need a specific name for the table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created three table which is country table, countryevents table, and country_countryevents table.
The first question i would like to know, is that need the specific name for the table?

Here is how i create the table:
The first one is country table:

```
 Schema::create('country', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

The second one is countryevents table :

```
 Schema::create('countryevents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('start');
            $table->string('end');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

The last one is my country_countryevents table:

```
   Schema::create('country_countryevents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('country')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('country_events_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('country_events_id')->references('id')->on('countryevents')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('editable');
            $table->timestamps();


        });
```

I not sure what is going on with my code here, cause i cant attach the event with my country.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
not found: 1146 Table 'calendar.country_country__events' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `cou
ntry_country__events` (`country__events_id`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values
 (1, 1, 2016-01-27 15:31:03, 2016-01-27 15:31:03))'
```

This is my error when i run the php artisan tinker, and want to connect them.

I am sure my model is correct, here is the Country.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='country';


    public function country_events(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country_Events')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is my Country_Events.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country_Events extends Model
{
    protected $table='countryevents';


    public function country(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is my error there?Thanks.

Comment: the problem is the referencing of the table `country_countryevents` as `country_country__events`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to reference the table name and probably the foreign and local keys as well.

Country Model:

```
public function country_events(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Country_Events',
        'country_countryevents',
        'country_id',
        'country_events_id'
    )->withTimestamps();
}
```

Country_Events Model:

```
public function country(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Country',
        'country_countryevents',
        'country_events_id',
        'country_id'
    )->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i try your method then it didnt show up the error but now it turns to another error which is`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function attach() in eval()'d code o
n line 1
` ,

Comment: Please include your code where you make the call to attach()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your reference to the table `country_countryevents` as `country_country__events`

Check the tablename in your database to see how it created this table in the end.

for more info check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14449912/3664960)

[Convention table names (with underscore)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14449912/3664960)

please also keep in mind to add this to your model if you don't plan to use conventional table names:

```
public $table = 'your_table_name';
```

Comment: ya, i got put the $table inside the model.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the name of the database is link with your country_countryevents. Then it should be works fine.